# Get Type from Metatype

Tags: swift, types

I'm struggling to understand the different between Types and Metatypes in swift 4. In particular I am looking to create an array something like this:

```
class A { ... }

class B {

    func doStuff() {
        let otherType = A.self
        let itemArr : [otherType] = // Objects of type A
    }

}
```

This throws a compile time error of `Use of undeclared type 'otherType'` which I think is occurring because `otherType` is actually `A.Type`. I think this may have something to do with Generics, but the catch is the type might not be known at compile time...

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: Can you show a more complete example of what you're trying to do?  How you're going to use itemArr, etc.

Comment: Essentially, I want to create a list of object of different types, so something like:

    `for subtype in [A1.type, A2.type, A3.type] {`
        `let itemArr : [subtype]`
        `// Normal stuff that you might expect to do to an array of objects...`
    `}`

Comment: This example doesn't really make sense, since the compiler will be able to infer the type of `itemArr` since you're assigning values to it at the same time as you declare it, so there's no need for type annotation using the type stored in a variable.

Comment: @DávidPásztor, the issue is I want to do this in a loop, and i'm working with subclasses so I need to be able to explicitly state the type of the objects in the array

Comment: What is "normal stuff that you might expect to do to an array of objects"?  If the code in this loop is using any functions/properties of these types then they either need to be ones which are declared in a common superclass or you will need to cast each individual object in the array to a specific subclass.  In either case you should be declaring your array as containing whatever the common superclass is.

Comment: @dan So I have a list of items of type `superclass` and I need to loop through each one and create lists for each of the subclasses. I realise I am not explaining myself very well here so if its not clear please keep asking :)

Comment: The problem is that the compiler needs to know the variable types at compile time, but the (dynamic) metatype values aren't known until runtime. Even if you could express `let itemArr : [otherType]`, the only thing the compiler knows about `otherType` is that its some metatype for a class that inherits from (or is) `A` – so what you would be expressing would be no different to `let itemArr : [A]`.

Comment: @mbamber This may be a lot clearer if you'll write out the loop you describe to "create lists for each of the subclasses" in your question. As asked, your code is identical to `[A]` (as Hamish notes), so it's unclear why you wouldn't use `[A]`. You should provide an actual example where `[A]` doesn't work. I suspect the underlying problem you're trying to solve is actually quite simple; it only has become complicated because of describing it in terms of metatypes.

Comment: If the type cannot be known at compile time, how would you use the object? There are no methods you can call on an unknown type, so what would a line of code that used this array look like? If the answer is `as?` casting, you're probably thinking about the problem incorrectly (not always, but usually).

Comment: @RobNapier So I was looking to do something like this: [https://codedump.io/share/YmGP3mea0RPG/1/metatypeloopquestion]

Hopefully this makes my intentions a bit clearer. It specifically revolves around encoding an array containing various subtypes

Comment: I don't quite understand what the code you've linked would be used for. The Encodable protocol is very capable of encoding an array containing subtypes without any trickery or metatypes. Perhaps you want to rewrite the question in terms of the deeper goal? Using `NSStringFromClass` for anything but debugging is almost certainly the wrong direction in Swift. What is the final JSON you expect, and what's the input data structure? Encodable is very powerful without needing ObjC runtime tricks or AnyClass.

Comment: I'm particularly confused by your code, because I don't see anything that requires `A` or `B` to be Encodable themselves, so I don't see how the final loop would work.

Answer (score 0):

Swift is powerful because you can pass types as parameters and create variable of types. This is attractive, but yet, there is better solution for your issue.

Define `protocol CustomArrayPopulatable {}` And add this to all subclasses/classes that could be added to the array. E.G. `A1: CustomArrayPopulatable` ; `A2: CusstomArrayPopulatable`.

With generic types, you could achieve great abstraction. However, have in mind, if you need to cast to specific subtype later on, you would need to cast it yourself such as: `if type as? A1 {...}`, so use generics carefully and think before you start, do you really need them.

Comment: Could you explain in a bit more detail how you would use this protocol to achieve what I would like?

Comment: It is considered better implementation in Swift to move the common logic in protocol. You can later on extend the protocol with for-all-clases implementation of a function or let the classes to implement for themselves if you want. With this, you can create array of the protocol type, implementing common function, that improves the abstraction, and you can put different types of objects in this array. Please take your time and watch https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/408/  I think with would be of great help for you. Happy Coding.